# pandas: coloured cells in excel output depending on column values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

I want to export a data frame to excel with pandas and I want to add colours depending on the first column (odd numbers -> colour A, even numbers -> colour B).

I have a small example below which does not produce any errors, but the resulting excel file has no colours in the cell. Any idea why this is happening? I am using Python 3.7.4 and Pandas 0.24.2. Thank you.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6]})

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/tmp/pandas_conditional3.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#FFC7CE',
                               'font_color': '#9C0006'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#C6EFCE',
                               'font_color': '#006100'})

worksheet.conditional_format('A1:A8', {'type':     'cell',
                                       'criteria': '=MOD(ROW(),2)',
                                       'value': 0,
                                       'format':   format1})
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:A8', {'type':     'cell',
                                       'criteria': '=MOD(ROW(),2)',
                                       'value': 1,
                                       'format':   format2})

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `type` of your `conditional_format` to `formula`:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:A8', {'type':     'formula',
                                       'criteria': '=MOD(ROW(),2)=0',
                                       'format':   format1})
worksheet.conditional_format('A1:A8', {'type':     'formula',
                                       'criteria': '=MOD(ROW(),2)=1',
                                       'format':   format2})
```